# Kdiff3 show conflict even that files have equal text and are binary equals

Tags: diff, merge

Like in title. Kdiff3 info dialogue shows that ( i do 2 way merge):

Total number of conflicts: 0
Nr of automatically solved conflicts: 0
Nr of unsolved conflicts: 0
kdiff3 files a and b have equal text

and all that is true but why should i save all those equal files manually?

Comment: What does `git diff` show?

Comment: I don't use it in `git` context.

Comment: Then shouldn't git be removed from the tags?

Comment: Yes you're right. I just couldn't create new tag and so I used git instead. I admit it wasn't best idea.

Comment: K3diff tag couldn't be used by me neither, so i used a diff tag. On a different note, what does diff (terminal) show? Maybe it's just an empty space/bug in k3diff

Comment: Have you done a Digest on the files? md5sum both files, see if they match.

Comment: I have to have 10 rep to add images, so heregoes dialog box image: http://i59.tinypic.com/2d8pbfn.jpg

Comment: @SebastianPiskorski looks like it's a bug, can you try another tool, like diff/diffuse/meld

Answer (score 0):

Kdiff3 can't handle some caracters (the ones with accents...).
It is supposed to work with the diffrent encoding but it bypass the letters it doesn't support.
If you need an entire file from place A to B, copy and paste it to be sure ;)

Comment: Copying and pasting isn't the best idea, because clipboard may change encoding. For example, Windows clipboard always changes encoding of characters to UTF-8.